# Repository Query:searching inside an array

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a MongoDb Document, quiz...

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(
 *      collection      = "Quizzes",
 *      repositoryClass = "Company\MyBundle\Repository\QuizRepository",
 *      slaveOkay = true
 * )
 */
class Quiz extends QuizEntity
```

The quiz contains many questions

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="QuizQuestion", name="questions")
 */
protected $questions = array();
```

If i have the main ID of a question, how can i query the repository of the Quiz for it?

(meaning, find a quiz contains my question with the id=4333)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use something like

```
/* $question = your question */

$dql = 'SELECT z FROM YourBundle:Quiz z INNER JOIN z.questions q WITH q= :question';  

$yourQuery->setParameter('question', $question);
```